# Jquery expanding ul list active state

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have some code that acts as an unordered list dropdown menu. It shows and hides well, but I am trying to work out how to make it add an active state to a parent element that is clicked if a nested child list exists. The code below seems to add the active state to any link that is clicked, whether it has children or not, but I don't want that.

For example I want to add an active state to 'In the News' when it is clicked.

Please could someone help me?

My jQuery:

```
$('.infobox.lightbox.inlinks ul > li > ul')
 .hide()
 .click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
 });

 $('.infobox.lightbox.inlinks ul > li').toggle(function(){
   $(this).find('ul').slideDown(),
   $(this).addClass("expanded");
 }, function(){
   $(this).find('ul').slideUp(),
   $(this).removeClass("expanded");
 });
```

and my HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Press releases</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">In the news</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Photo galleries</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Podcasts</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Media Centre</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Fact Sheet</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Press Contacts</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Declare a `state` variable out of your function. Test now for the current state and change this variable to the state you need.

Comment: Im Sorry that sounds good, but I'm not sure how to code that - could you show an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JQuery's `.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) is used to hide/show elements, not "toggle" between functions.

What you want to do something like this (although, there are plenty of other ways to go about it):

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$('.infobox.lightbox.inlinks ul > li').click(function(e){
     if($(this).children('ul').length>0){
         e.preventDefault();
         if($(this).children('ul').is(':visible')){
           $(this).find('ul').slideUp(),
           $(this).removeClass("expanded");
         }else{
           $(this).find('ul').slideDown(),
           $(this).addClass("expanded"); 
         }
     }
 });
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/aZBXc/6/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Dom, this really almost works, except when I click the ul link in my list the page jumps to the top. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: That is because of `<a></a>`. In that case, you will want to use `.preventDefault()`. I fixed my initial post. This should give you the results you want.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you so much. I added `$(".infobox.lightbox.inlinks ul ul").hide();` to hide the expanded box when you first hit the page. You're a lifesaver!

Comment: No problem! You can also hide the expanded box by adding `display:none;` to your css then you wouldn't need `$(".infobox.lightbox.inlinks ul ul").hide();`. Let me know if you have any other questions!

Comment: Thank Dom, I decided to use JS to hide them not css, just in case JS is switched off. That way everything should show still

Answer (score 0):

Use this html...

```
<div class="infobox lightbox inlinks">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Press releases</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">In the news</a>
            <ul style="display:none;">
              <li><a href="#">Photo galleries</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Podcasts</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Media Centre</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Fact Sheet</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Press Contacts</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the JS...

```
$('.infobox.lightbox.inlinks ul > li').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).find('ul').slideToggle(),
});
```

Not use the `jQuery` ready... use the jQuery `on` event...

See this [jSfiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/aZBXc/3/)